# Etymology of the municipality Pomas

Tags: étymologie, géographie, france

What is the etymology of the name of the municipality "Pomas", located between Carcassonne and Limoux?

It is pronounced both with and without a voiced "s", I believe locally with the voiced s.

Has it something to do with pommes?

Answer (score 2):

French Wikipedia page of Pomas said it was called "Pomars" before which could come from "vergers de pommiers", that is to say apple orchard so maybe a link yes

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomas